# Density of the orbit of a pure state.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a simple unital $C^*$-algebra and denote $U(A)$ the group of unitaries in $A$.

For $u\in U(A)$ lets define the $^*$-automorphism $\text{Ad}u:A\to A$ given by $a\mapsto uau^*$.

It is a known fact that if $\varphi$ is a pure state of $A$ then the set $\{\varphi\circ\text{Ad}u:u\in U(A)\}$ is weak*-dense in the space of pure states of $A$. There exists some variants that also holds and it is not necessary to consider the set of $\textbf{all}$ unitaries in $A$. For example, the set $\{\varphi\circ\text{Ad}\exp(ia):0\leq a\leq\pi\}$ is also a weak*-dense subset of the pure state space.

I am wondering if it is possible to require the unitaries to be "not to far from 1", that is, if for all $\epsilon>0$ the set $\{\varphi\circ\text{Ad}u:\|1-u\|<\epsilon\}$ is weak*-dense in the pure state space.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer did not satisfy all assumptions from the question, as was pointed out by Aweygan in the comments, but one can fix this by considering the finite-dimensional case instead

Let $A=M_n(\mathbb{C})$. The states of the form $\phi_\xi=\langle\,\cdot\,\xi,\xi\rangle$ for $\xi\in \mathbb{C}^n$ with $\|\xi\|=1$ are pure states on $A$, and $\phi_\xi\circ \mathrm{Ad}(u)=\phi_{u^\ast\xi}$. Let $\xi,\eta\in H$ be orthogonal unit vectors and $p$ the orthogonal projection onto the span of $\eta$. If $u$ is unitary with $\|1-u\|<\epsilon$, then
$$
|\langle pu^\ast\xi,u^\ast\xi\rangle|\leq \|p(u^\ast \xi-\xi)\|+\|p\xi\|<\epsilon,
$$
while $\langle p\eta,\eta\rangle=1$. Thus $\phi_\eta$ does not lie in the weak$^\ast$ closure of $\{\phi_\xi\circ\mathrm{Ad}(u)\colon \|1-u\|<\epsilon\}$ if $\epsilon<1$.

Comment: It looks like the asker wanted the algebra to be unital, and that the unitaries lie in the algebra.

Comment: @Aweygan You are absolutely right. One can fix this by considering the finite-dimensional case instead.